# Generative Adversarial Networks do not use sampled noise in a particular setting?

Tags: neural-networks, noise, generative-models, gan

I am trying to find out a paper that mentioned that in a conditional setting, generative adversarial networks overlook the sampled noise. Please let me know if this is not the right place or way to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this paper 
["Image-to-Image Translation with Conditional Adversarial Networks"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07004), but the way how the noise is added is not described in the paper.

> Past conditional GANs have acknowledged this and provided Gaussian noise z as an input to the generator, in addition to x (e.g., [54]). In initial experiments, we did not find this strategy effective – the generator simply learned to ignore the noise – which is consistent with Mathieu et
>   al. [39].